# Using while let with two variables simultaneously

Tags: rust, option-type

I'm learning Rust and have been going through leetcode problems. One of them includes merging two linked lists, whose nodes are optional. I want to write a while loop that would go on until at least 1 node becomes `None`, and I was trying to use the `while let` loop for that.

However, it looks like the `while let` syntax supports only one optional, e.g.:

```rust
while let Some(n) = node {
   // do stuff
}
```

but I can't write

```rust
while let Some(n1) = node1 && Some(n2) = node2 {
}
```

Am I misunderstanding the syntax? I know I can rewrite it with a `while true` loop, but is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Also, can one do multiple checks with `if let`? Like `if let None=node1 && None=node2 {return}`

Comment: For the time being (although IIRC there is work being done to patch this) you can't mix `if let` statements with boolean conditions.

Comment: `let (Some(n1), Some(n2)) = (node1, node2)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pattern match with [`Option::zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.zip):

```rust
while let Some((n1, n2)) = node1.zip(node2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what @Netwave said, on nightly you can use the unstable [`let_chains`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667) feature:

```rust
#![feature(let_chains)]

while let Some(n1) = node1 && let Some(n2) = node2 {
    // ...
}
```